# Amazon Route53 domain not linking to Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I'm a complete newbie to networking so bear with me.  FYI I am using the pre-bundled Ubuntu 16.04 instance on Amazon Lightsail.  I am building a Django project.

I have a domain registered on Route53 that I am trying to link to my Lightsail project.  I created a [DNS zone](https://i.gyazo.com/04b0432274f659474fad409e2d1fd81b.png) and [static IP](https://i.gyazo.com/5e8f421c3e703e058521792e3efc4ab3.png) following the Lightsail docs.  Then I created the appropriate [A and NS records](https://i.gyazo.com/0d3312171de403c8deebf5d0f8e00d4b.png) in the Hosted Zone in Route53.

But when I run the Django server from the command line, using port `0.0.0.0:8000` (after doing `sudo ufw allow 8000`), I cannot connect to `bungol.com:8000`.  I used [this](https://ip-lookup.net/domain.php) website to check if `bungol.com` is correctly linked but it seems there is no ip address attached to the domain.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Firstly, why is this not working?
2. Secondly, how do I go about troubleshooting such an issue?  There are so many things here that could have caused the issue and I'm clueless as to how I should start solving the problem.

Comment: I just figured it out.  I had to link the namespace of the domain itself to the namespace of the Hosted Zone.  I was linking the domain's namespace to the static IP in Lightsail and that was the problem.

Comment: Would you mind describing how you did that linking of the namespace of the Hosted Zone?  I'm having the same problem and just can't make sense of Amazon's documentation at the moment.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. I don't use Route53. And i'm using a country specific domain not ".com". Can't find the reason. I have worked with many other domains and servers apart from Lightsail. Hope someone help to solve this.

Comment: @Valachio can you be more specific on the steps you followed to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Valchio your solution doesn't make sense the way it's written, can you elaborate? I've been struggling with this for days

Answer (score 1):

Answer, you did everything correctly.

How long did you wait after configuring your DNS records? Your screenshot does not show the TTL values, but you would have to wait at least that long usually.

I just went to your site www.bungol.com and it works. The IP address 19.221.198.143 matches based upon a ping.

Comment: Yes I just managed to figure it out.  Banging my head against the next problem now...  thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

There is some conflicting information in the docs ([see discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=817596&tstart=0)). The trick is to use Lightsail only to set up a static IP and use that IP for the A record on the Route53 side.

No need to set up a DNS zone in Lightsail or deal with its nameservers.